# Why the decryption key is the inverse of the encryption key in RSA?

Tags: rsa

In public key encryption (RSA scheme) encryption key `e` and decryption key `d` are the inverses of each other. If so, when `e` is `3`, why the value of `d` is not `1/3` since `3` and `1/3` are inverses of each other?

Comment: This is a better question for [Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com)

Comment: It is the inverse over integral fields.

Comment: It's not the "normal" inverse you learn about in introductory algebra courses. It's the [**modular** multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse).

Comment: More relevant at http://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking of the algebraic inverse, not the modular inverse.

If 3 is congruent to 3 mod 4, the inverse is 3 is congruent to -1 mod 4